# TypeError: GoogleMap is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I passed an API data to my map component and when i use map function to use the location in the api data for marker, i got this error: "this is undefined" and it points to the GoogleMap tag but the map works if i take away the marker part of the code. What have i done wrong?

I have added this const google = window.google; to the beginning of my code but it doesn't work. Below is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

function Maps() {

  return (

    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={14}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 60.169857, lng: 24.938379 }}
    >

      {this.props.apiData.map((event => (

        <Marker
          key={event.id}
          position={{
            lat: event.location.lat,
            lng: event.location.lon
          }}

        />

      )))}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Maps));


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {

    console.log(this.props.apiData);
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
        <WrappedMap
          googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`}
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
        />

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

I expect to see the marker on the screen but it only shows this error saying "GoogleMap is not defined".